(When) does conditioning commute with products?
This is related to my previous question. In it, I was told

Under the (very strong) independence conditions that $X_0\mid E_0$ is independent of $E_1$ and $X_1\mid E_1$ is independent of $E_0$, we have that
$$(X_0+X_1)\mid(E_0\cap E_1)=X_0\mid (E_0\cap E_1)+X_1\mid (E_0\cap E_1)=X_0\mid E_0+X_1\mid E_1\tag{1}$$

I am curious if (1) holds if one swaps ever addition with multiplication.
It seems like it should be true, but I do not know.

What do you mean by $X_0|E_0$? It is not something that has a standard definition. One has things like the conditional expectation $E(X_0|E_0)$, or conditional probabilities like $P(X_0\in A|E_0)$, and one can talk about the (conditional) distribution of $X_0$ given $E_0$. But for just "$X_0|E_0$" on its own, it's not at all clear what you would mean.

To take an example, suppose $X$ is a fair dice roll, uniform on ${1,2,3,4,5,6}$. Let $E_0$ be the event that $X$ is even, and $E_1$ the event that $X$ is at least $4$. What would "$X|E_0 + X|E_1$" mean there?

I mean the conditional distribution of $X_0$ given $E_0$. Is there better notation for this? As you mention, conditional expectation and conditional probability already have standard notation.

Then what do you mean by the addition of two distributions? What is "$X|E_0+X|E_1$" in the example I gave? (Remember that knowing the distribution of $Y_0$ and the distribution of $Y_1$ is not enough to tell you the distribution of $Y_0+Y_1$ in general. You need to know about their joint distribution.)

About notation: you might sometimes see something like $\mathcal{L}(X|A)$ for the distribution (or "law") of a random variable $X$ given an event $A$. Or something like $p_{X|A}(.)$ for the probability mass function of $X$ given $A$, or $f_{X|A}(.)$ for the probability density function of $X$ given $A$, of $F_{X|A}(.)$ for the cumulative distribution function of $X$ given $A$.

Perhaps this will help. $X_0$, $X_1$ are independent random variables, and $E_i$ is an event solely defined in terms of $X_i$ (think "$X_i \leq c$"). I (was) interested in whether the convolution $\mathcal{L}(X_0\mid E_0) + \mathcal{L}(X_1 \mid E_1)$ has law $\mathcal{L}(X_0 + X_1 \mid E_0\cap E_1)$. I am also interested in a similar statement for products.

OK that sounds fine - so specifically "convolution" of two distributions means the distribution of what you get when you add together independent samples from the two distributions. Indeed, your statement can hold in some cases but is not true in general. Probably not much difference between the case of sums and of products. At least if you take $X_0, X_1$ positive, then you can put $Y_0=\log X_0$ and $Y_1=\log X_1$, and multiplying $X_0$ and $X_1$ is equivalent to adding $Y_0$ and $Y_1$ (but any independence properties are preserved).

I think the best conditions I can give here are the same as in the previous related post - you can find such an event if $X_0$ and $X_1$ are conditionally independent given an auxillary event.
Generally, there is no reason for there to be a nice such event in both the sum and product case.
